# How can I wrap a library to allow me to switch it out more easily?

Tags: java, scala, types, jsoup

The title basically says it all. I am using Jsoup to scrape Hackernews, and then I'm making a restful api to return json of the scraped info.

I've been told that wrapping the libraries you use is a good idea. So I'm wondering how can I do that? For example using Jsoup I am given a 'Document' back that holds the html. This type bleeds through to every function I'm using, basically. I select and element from that 'Document' and I'm given 'Elements' back, and then that bleeds through.

How would I go about wrapping a library and manage the types that come along with that library?

I hope this is enough information. If you have any questions, or need more info let me know.

Comment: Perhaps make your own types, and simply forward the pertinent methods and such to the library of your own choice? I *think* I remember reading about that as a possibility somewhere, although as I haven't done it myself I'm not sure if it's quite what you're looking for.

Comment: So, are you saying that I should try and contain the types specific to Jsoup (or any other library) to models? Have some model that contains a Document?

I thought about this solution. If a change of libraries came down the pipe then the models would surely change, and the function logic would change but the interface the wrapper provides would stay the same.

Comment: This sounds like a general design question that might be better asked at Programmers -- but search and check the help center first to ensure it's on topic.

Comment: @user2767260 Something like that? Think up of the types that your application needs, then do your best to freeze that API and make the library work behind the scenes to fit that. Sure, changing libraries *might* require you to make some changes, but if you do your design right those changes *should* be abstracted away into those wrapper classes. But I agree with Jeffrey -- you might want to consider posting on Programmers if it's on-topic there.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a [structural design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Structural) such as the *Adapter* pattern would suit you best. [**Adapters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) are meant to join two incompatible pieces of software to each other. They are a suitable means to encapsulate an API and translate back and forth to a form that is more natural or intuitive to your own software. Be sure to reflect upon how the API you are using may change in the future so you can design your Adapter with this in mind.